# Fullscreen mode on exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm developing an app that contains an exoplayer, and I need to make it play in fullscreen mode.

While the video is full screen, the user can watch the video in portrait or landscape mode.

So far I created a button to display the video in fullscreen.

```
 holder.simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context);

            // Bind the player to the view.
            holder.videoCtn.setPlayer(holder.simpleExoPlayer);

            holder.videoUri = Uri.parse(mensagem.getVideo());

            // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
            DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
                    Util.getUserAgent(context, context.getString( R.string.app_name)));
            // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
            MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(holder.videoUri);
            // Prepare the player with the source.
            holder.simpleExoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);

            //botao full screen video
            holder.exo_fullscreen_icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   //Make the video come fullscreen ...
            });
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setResizeMode method
[Check this](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/AspectRatioFrameLayout.ResizeMode.html)